# In spark, how to run several `collect` concurrently

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop2, bigdata

I am new to Spark, and I'm not sure I understand the way it distributes jobs very well.

I have the following code:

```
c1 = dict(smallrdd1.collect())
bigrdd1 = bigrdd1.filter(lambda val: c1[val])

c2 = dict(smallrdd2.collect())
bigrdd2 = bigrdd2.filter(lambda val: c2[val])
```

If I understand well, the two `collect` will be run on the main job, not concurrently, and this will slow down the whole process. How to do in order to have spark execute the collects and filter in separate jobs, on separate nodes ?

EDIT

I think my question wasn't very clear. I'll try to make it more concrete.

What I want to implement is an efficient star map-join on column-oriented data. That is, I have a few dimension tables, that each have a few million key-values. When stored as a raw python `dict`, or a scala `Map`, they are a few hundred Mb each. That's small enough to fit in memory individually on each node, but all together, they make up a few Gb, and don't fit in memory.

On the other side, for each of these small dimension columns, I have a big fact column, that has a few billion rows, and sure doesn't fit in memory.

The idea was to manage data location inside the cluster so that each of the big tables is on a different node. Then launch several tasks, each one responsible for one join. Then load the dimension tables from disk and create the hashmaps *concurrently*, then «broadcast» the hashmaps only to those tasks that need it. Then, join the big fact columns with the dimension tables.

Comment: two collect's are not going to run concurrently, it is sequential. And main thing is when you collect, it is going to collect all the elements to Driver, when you use any transformations or actions like filter, map etc... its going to run on separate nodes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But in my case, I need to have these `dict` only on the executors that will do the filters. I don't need them on the driver. 

Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: i am not sure what is that dict... but why are you collecting first then filter? when you use filter its going to run on executors.

Comment: Yes, of course the filter is going to run on the executors. I'm trying to implement a parallel map-side join. These dict are the hashtables of my small tables.

Answer (score 1):

So, `collect` along `take` and `first` are typically used for testing and debugging. As @Shankar wrote, `collect` will pull all data to the driver, which is fine for small data sets used during testing, but not fine when dealing with huge data set, as it will kill your driver with an OOM.

Now, you say that you want to do a join, so just use `join`:

```
val joined = bigrdd.join(smallrdd, bigrdd.col("id") === smallrdd.col("id"))
```

(this is Scala syntax, but I'm sure you get the point)

Now the data is joined on your workers and you can continue with filters, maps and other transformations :)

Comment: Yes, of course, I could use `join`. But the problem is that join is a costly operation, that is not necessary when `smallrdd` is small enough.

Comment: What you propose is a *reduce-side* join, and I want to do a *map-side* join.

If I get it correctly, spark will not automatically build a hashmap with my small rdd, but will in the background do a costly **shuffle** operation, if I use `join`. Am i right?

Comment: Look, we are trying to help you, but you clearly seem to know best, so I'm not sure, why you are posting here on SO. I can tell you that I have been using Spark for 2 years now and if you look at my profile you will se that 96% of my reputation here on SO stems from answering Spark questions, so I know a little bit about programming in Spark. To parallelise your query you need to use `join`. If your smallrdd is really small, why do you even load it as an rdd? Simply use a normal array and broadcast that.

Comment: I'm really sorry if i seemed agressive, it was not the goal! Each smallrdd is small enough to fit in memory, indeed, but maybe the `smallrdd1` + `smallrdd2` don't fit. The problem with just broadcasting one, then the other is that it is sequential. I was wondering  if there was a way to to that in parallel.

Comment: The smallrdds would have to fit into a regular array to be broadcasted. If they cannot, then your smallrdds are not _that_ small and you need to do a `join`. It is true that `join` will cause a shuffle of data, but Spark was built for this and it's really good at it. Of course, you should be wary of how much data you are shuffling, and make sure you are not shuffling the same data around multiple times, but most jobs require shuffling. Your job is not to avoid shuffles, but to avoid _unnecessary_ shuffles.

Comment: OK, thank you for this explanation. In my case, I have smallrdds that are small enough to fit in memory one at a time, but not all together. If I were to do everything manually, I would load all the smallrdd in memory inside my nodes, so that each node had 1 hashmap in memory. Than do the joins using the hashmaps, and then throw the hashmap away. That way, I wouldn't have done any shuffle. Is there a way to have spark doing that ?

Comment: Well as long as you are dealing with one smallrdd (or actually not rdd, but array) at the time, you can broadcast that, do your computations (in parallel), destroy the variable, create a new variable, broadcast that etc. I would, however, strongly encourage you to simply do the `join` and see if processing time is even an issue.

Comment: I edited the question in order to make it clearer, and posted an answer. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the short answer to my question is simply *it's not possible*.

From the answers I got, I think this is simply **not possible to do with spark**. The only possibilities we have is creating all the hasmaps in the driver, or use the traditional spark `join`.

#### Inside the driver

Sequentially load the small dimension tables and then broadcast them to all executors (which is sequential, and induces Gbs of useless data movement) :

```
c1 = sc.broadcast(smallrdd1.collectAsMap())
bigrdd1 = bigrdd1.filter(lambda val: c1.value[val])

c2 = sc.broadcast(smallrdd2.collectAsMap())
bigrdd2 = bigrdd2.filter(lambda val: c1.value[val])
```

#### On the executors

Doesn't compute anything on the driver, but computes the join slower, because it involves shuffle operations on the large datasets.

```
bigrdd1 = bigrdd1 \
              .map(lambda (bigk,bigv):(bigv,bigk)) \
              .join(smallrdd1) \
              .map(lambda (bigv,(bigk,smallv)):(bigk,bigv))
bigrdd2 = bigrdd2 \
              .map(lambda (bigk,bigv):(bigv,bigk)) \
              .join(smallrdd2) \
              .map(lambda (bigv,(bigk,smallv)):(bigk,bigv))
```

Comment: I'm afraid that you will not get my up vote here. What you are trying to do, simply isn't how you do things in Spark, but instead of accepting that and embracing the Spark way, you seem to hang on to this idea of collecting rdds as a preferred solution... I very much disagree with that - don't know what else say.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I looked stubborn or if I made you waste your time. But I'm really trying to implement an algorithm here, not just to get things done.

Comment: And for those who would be interested, I still put working Spark code in my answer. What else could I do?